# WCF windows integrated security: got 401 while accessing from remote client machines

Tags: windows, wcf, security

I am trying to make a simple demo of WCF sevice with windows integrated security.

IIS has been set for the website: Anonymous Authetication disabled, only Windows Authetication enabled.

- Tried to access the service locally on the server, it works
  http://servername:82/
- Tried to access the service remotely from other client machines,
  "page could not be found" error comes out, and in IIS log file, 401
  status returned for the request.
- If enable Anonymous Authetication, accessing remotely starts to work.

Any idea to troubleshooting for this specific issue?

Below is the configuration file for the WCF service.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows">      
    </authentication>

  </system.web>


<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior" name="WcfServiceDemo.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
      name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="WcfServiceDemo.IService1">          
    </endpoint>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>  


</configuration>
```

Comment: Are the remote clients running under a domain service account? Or a local one?

Comment: under a domain account

Comment: I am just using IE trying to open the WCF URL, like (http://servername:82/)